# PHP non-numeric value warning

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Does anyone have the solution? (I'm a beginner.)

**EDIT:**

Here is the code:

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
    $items[] = $r;              
}

$itemArray = array($items[0][0]=>array('Proid' => $items[0][0], 
    'name'=>$items[0][1], 'brand'=>$items[0][2], 'desc'=>$items[0][3], 
    'quan'=>$_POST["quantity"], 'price'=>$items[0][4], 'image'=> $items[0][5]));

$_SESSION['cart'] += $itemArray;

$i = $item['Proid'];    
$tp = $item['quan'] * $item['price'];
$tp2 += $tp;
```

Comment: What are your values?

Comment: Well, if I were to guess, it sounds like a non-numeric value was encountered.  You can only perform math with numeric values.

Comment: $tp = $item['quan'] * $item['price'];

Comment: Those are all variables, we can't guess what the values are.

Comment: @AavVerzosa Either `$item['quan']` or `$item['price']` is a non-numeric value (probably a string).

Comment: @AavVerzosa If you're getting the values from a `POST` then probably one or both are being passed in as strings rather than numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some of your values are a `string`, not a `integer` or `float`.

To make sure, use

[`intval()` to convert a `string` to `integer`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.intval.php)

or

[`floatval()` to convert a `string` to `float`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floatval.php).

This is just a warning, php will try to convert it behind the scenes, but if may not be accurate, for example, if you use `,` as decimal separator, or if you use some thousand separator.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which PHP version you are using but a Warning will be emitted if a non-numeric value is encountered. See this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php).

so what you can do is before doing calculation make sure you check if the entity is numeric or not and for that you can use is_numeric() PHP function.

For example in your case :

```
if(is_numeric($item['quan']) && is_numeric($item['price'])){
     $tp = $item['quan'] * $item['price'];
}
```